# Ngbmodal content using template URL

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Playing around with NgbModal,

I have a ngbmodal component :
My goal is to use a templateUrl for the content instead of defining the content in the template (currrently commented out) as show in the code below.

**info-modal.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'info-modal-content',
    templateUrl: './info.modal.content.html'
    /* template:  `<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello, {{person.FirstName}}!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>` */


})
export class InfoModalContent {
    @Input() person:Person

    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}


@Component({
    selector: 'info-modal',
    templateUrl: './info.modal.html'
})
export class InfoModal {
    constructor(private activeModal:NgbModal) {}

    open(person:Person) {
        const modalRef = this.activeModal.open(InfoModalContent)
        modalRef.componentInstance.person = person;
    }
}
```

**info.modal.content.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, {{person.FirstName}}!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      </div>`
```

Reason for asking is, when I try to do so, the page doesn't render correctly. (It opens the page where I came from originally in a popup window).

Whenever I uncomment the template (and comment the templateUrl) it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think we can help without a reproduce scenario... Can you try to reproduce it in a plunker? You can start with this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/4eGW8PQHH0LRGupvpEII?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7KaaleqFp2QUgL4Ur3vb?p=preview

Seems to work just fine. Rechecking my own code again :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself:

**templateUrl: './info.modal.content.html'**

Should be :

**templateUrl: '%copmplete path%/info.modal.content.html'**

Thanks for your help,